# Recurrence for T(n) for a Partition Function

Tags: algorithm, big-o, recurrence

I am trying to determine a recurrence for a function and then solve it using the master theorem. The function is as follows:

```
Partition(x, A[], lo, hi){  
   if(lo > hi)  
        return hi;  
    else{  
        q = (lo + hi) / 2;  
        if(A[q] >= x)  
            return Partition(x, A[], q+1, hi);  
       else  
            return Partition(x, A[], lo, q-1);  
}
```

One note: A is non-increasing,
From what I can understand, the recurrence should be:
T(n) = T(n/2 + 1) + T(n/2 -1)
as q is half of n to start +/- 1.
What I am unclear on is what the O(n) work would be if any for this function?

Comment: The +/- 1 does make the result slightly more complex, but the overall complexity is unchanged. As for the O(n) work, that will need to be provided by yourself, as (without any further assumptions) this algorithm is yours or from a question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the recurrence equation for the given algorithm is

T(n) = 1 + 1 + 1 + T(n/2)

1 => For the exit condition

1 => For the q calculation

1 => For the branch condition

T(n/2) => For the branch computation

Hence, T(n) = 3 + T(n/2)

**Applying Master Theorem:**

For recurrences of form,

```
T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)

where a >= 1 and b > 1
```

If f(n) is O(n<sup>c</sup>) then

1. If c < log<sub>b</sub>a, then T(n) = O(n * log<sub>b</sub>a)
2. If c = log<sub>b</sub>a, then T(n) = O(n<sup>c</sup> * log n)
3. if c > log<sub>b</sub>a, then T(n) = O(n<sup>c</sup>)

we have a = 1, b = 2, c = 0 and c = log<sub>b</sub>a (case 2)[as c = 0 and log 1 (any base) = 0]

Therefore, T(n) = O (n<sup>0</sup> * log n)

> T(n) = O (log n)